# VBA on refresh added PivotItems are selected by default

Tags: excel, pivotitem, vba

When I refresh my data and then do a refresh on my pivot table using the following code, new added items are selected by default. Is there away to prevent this as it means I have to go in again and deselect?

```
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    For Each pt In Worksheets("Summary").PivotTables

    pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh

    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
       pf.AutoSort xlAscending, pf.Name
    Next pf
    Next pt

    Set pf = Nothing
    Set pt = Nothing
```

Comment: How about right before `pt.PivotCache.Refresh` you put some code to load in all the selected items into an array / dictionary / collection. Then, after `pt.PivotCacheRefresh` you loop through the items and uncheck them if they are not in the array / dictionary / collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment above, something like this should work. If you have a lot of pivot fields you need to check, you could probably create some functions to make it easier or more efficient.

```
Sub pt()


Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Dim dict As Dictionary 'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

For Each pt In Worksheets("Summary").PivotTables

    pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone

    Set dict = New Dictionary

    ' you will need to loop through each Fields PivotItem Collection separately 
    For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("myPivotField").PivotItems
        dict.Add pi.Name, 1
    Next

    pt.PivotCache.Refresh

   'again, you will need to loop through each one separately to check
    For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("myPivotField").PivotItems
        If dict.Exists(pi.Name) Then Else: pi.Visible = False
    Next

    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
       pf.AutoSort xlAscending, pf.Name
    Next pf

Next pt

Set pf = Nothing
Set pt = Nothing

End Sub
```